# си, количество элементов в двумерном массиве, среднее арифметическое

Tags: c, массивы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите пожалуйста, мне необходимо вычислить среднее арифметическое 1 и 4 строк массива. Я нашел сумму этих строк и количество в каждой строке. Как найти количество в этих двух строках? и как найти среднее арифм. 1 и 4 строки? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void intrM (int n, int i, int j, int a[][10])
{
    if (i<n) if (j<n)
        printf("(%i,%i)= ",i,j),scanf("%i",&a[i][j]),intrM(n,i,j+1,a);
   else j=0, intrM(n,i+1,j,a);
}
 void afisM (int n, int i, int j, int a[][10])
 {
        if (i<n)
            if (j<n)
            printf("%5i",a[i][j]),afisM(n,i,j+1,a);
        else {puts(" ");afisM(n,i+1,0,a); }
 }
int sumM (int n, int i, int j, int a[][10], int s)
{
    if (j<n) {
        if (i==0||i==3) s+=a[i][j]; sumM(n,i,j+1,a,s);}
        else return s;
}
void sumT (int n, int i, int j, int a[][10])
{
    int s=0;
    if (i<n) {printf("\n%i= %i",i,sumM(n,i,j,a,s)); sumT(n,i+1,j,a);}
}
int kolvoM (int n, int i, int j, int a[][10], int k)
{
     if (j<n) {
        if (i==0||i==3) k++; kolvoM(n,i,j+1,a,k); }
        else return k;
}
void kolvoT (int n, int i, int j, int a[][10])
{
    int k=0;
    if (i<n) {printf("\n%i = %i",i,kolvoM(n,i,j,a,k)); kolvoT(n,i+1,j,a);}
}

main()
{
    int c[10][10];
    float sredn;
    intrM(4,0,0,c); afisM(4,0,0,c);
    sumT(4,0,0,c);
    puts("\n");
    kolvoT(4,0,0,c);

        puts("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А Вы типы возвращаемых значений для функций только в вопросе забыли указать, или в коде тоже?

Comment: исправил, но все равно чушь выходит

Comment: Я сейчас переформатирую самую верхнюю функцию, сделайте то же самое с основными, пожалуйста, и обновите вопрос. В текущем виде код очень тяжело читать.

Comment: Нет,я не могу это отформатировать, Вы хоть компилировать код пробовали? Да он же нерабочий совершенно!

Comment: я исправил, мне удалось найти сумму и количество в 1 и 4 строке по отдельности, но не знаю, как найти количество в 1 и 4 строке в общем, сумму двух строк,  и как найти среднее этих строк?

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно задача из Вашего вопроса решается так:

```
double getArithmeticMean(int** A, int rowNumber, size_t rowSize){
    if(rowSize == 0) throw "RowSize < 1; Matrix A is empty!";
    double tmp = 0.0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < rowSize; i++)
        tmp += A[rowNumber][i];
    return tmp / rowSize;
}

void readMatrix(int** A, size_t columnSize, size_t rowSize){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < columnSize; i++){
        for(size_t j = 0; j < rowSize; j++){
             printf("(%i,%i)= ",i,j);
             scanf("%i", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    int** A = new int*[10];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        A[i] = new int[10];

    readMatrix(A, 10, 10);

    double mean1 = getArithmeticMean(1, 1-1, 10);
    double mean4 = getArithmeticMean(1, 4-1, 10);
    double mean = (mean1 + mean4)/2.0;
    printf("mean is &d", mean);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Все остальные функции Вам нужны для чего-то другого.

А теперь хотелось бы немного позанудствовать на счет кода. Возьмем первую же Вашу функцию:

```
void intrM (int n, int i, int j, int a[][10])
{
    if (i<n) if (j<n)
        printf("(%i,%i)= ",i,j),scanf("%i",&a[i][j]),intrM(n,i,j+1,a);
    else j=0, intrM(n,i+1,j,a);
}
```

Во-первых. Я знаком с C и C++ около 8 лет, хотя никогда не писал на них промышленного кода и специалистом считаться никак не могу, но общее представление имею. И я **никогда** раньше даже не слышал об использовании запятой для записи нескольких операций в одну строку. Да, это работает. Использующие это будут гореть в аду. Не делайте так, понять, что делает Ваш код из-за таких вещей ооочень сложно.

Во-вторых. Вызываете функцию? Ставьте пробелы! Выполняете сравнение? Ставьте пробелы! Пробелов на клавиатуре количество бесконечное. А глаза людей, читающих Ваш код однажды портятся. Не пытайте глаза других.

И третье. Имена функций должны быть говорящими. Вы должны прочесть название функции и сразу понять, что она делает. Даже если писали код год назад. `intM` - это что-то странное. `askUserInputForMatrix` - сразу же говорит о том, что будет сделано. Если имя функции меньше 8 символов, то Вы придумали плохое имя. Желательно, чтобы имя было 10-15 символов. Если хоть раз в жизни Вы вернетесь к своему коду - будете невероятно благодарны себе прошлому за длинные имена функций.

Пример того, как могла бы выглядеть Ваша же верхняя функция, если привести ее в нормальный вид:

```
void askUserInputForMatrix(int n, int i, int j, int a[][10]){
    if (i < n) {
        if (j < n){
            printf("(%i, %i)= ", i, j);
            scanf("%i", &a[i][j]);
            askUserInputForMatrix(n, i, j+1, a);
        } else {
            j = 0;
            askUserInputForMatrix(n, i+1, j, a);
        }
    }
}
```

Места занимает больше. Но никому не придется ломать голову над тем, что Вы написали.